# Auto load popup on page load

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have just purchased a website template which included 'Sweet Alerts'.

On the template you have to click a button to show the pop up alert, see below code

```
 <button id="sweet-3" type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-success">Launch alert</button>
```

Is it possible to load this when the page loads?

Comment: Probably there is a JS binding a click evento to the button (id=sweet-3) that display the 'Sweet Alert'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on 'Sweet Alerts' documentation (http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) you could simply do something like this:

```
<body onload="sweetAlert('Test', 'Hello world', 'error');">
 <button id="sweet-3" type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-success">Launch alert</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Great thanks! Where in the documentation did you find this?

Comment: @user3092953 I just took the example on the first page's demo. If you are looking for more documentation on events you can check MDN for more details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: Great stuff, thank you! You havent seen anything about auto closing the pop ups have you?

Comment: @user3092953 same URL, check the section with "A message with auto close timer" or you can also check the `swal.close();` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.ready(function{
$('#sweet-3').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#sweet-3').click();
});
```